# restore database from dump via console

Tags: mysql

I am trying to restore database from db.sql dump 
I have installed mysql (both client and server), when I have installed server I defined password for root user
and I am trying to restore DB with such command

```
nnn@nnn:~/prj/myprj$mysql -user=root -password=qwerty <db.sql
```

But I get the following error 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ser=root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
I have just create this password so it could not be wrong. Perhaps something else wrong in syntax? (I am using ubuntu by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double dashes in front of long option names like `--user`, with singe dash it is taken as short option `-u` and the rest is taken as user name `ser=root`

So it is either

```
mysql --user=root --password=qwerty db_name < db.sql
```

or with short options

```
mysql -uroot -pqwerty db_name < db.sql
```

Comment: it helps but now ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected (same syntax - only long dashes before user and password. The db.sql file located in the same prj folder

Comment: When dumping a single database with `mysqldump` there will be no `CREATE DATABASE` or `USE DATABASE` statements in the dump file. So you need to add the name of the database you want to restore into on the command line, and make sure this database already exists.

Comment: You can add `-D` to the `mysql` command line to select the database you want to work with: `mysql -uroot -p -D stuff < db.sql` (I assumed your database is named "stuff")

Comment: -D is optional, just giving the name as last parameter is sufficient and common use